# Проблемы с MySQL: ошибка "Field 'description' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Есть например такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `a_test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `access` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Делаю запрос

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `a_test` SET `name` = 'Имя'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Ошибка:

> Field 'description' doesn't have a
> default value

3 движка поставил, довльно таки популярные, и всё время эта ошибка

> Field ... doesn't have a
> default value

Раньше ставил, было всё нормально.
В общем, проблема то ясна. Но править все таблицы не вариант. Такое ощущение, что проблема всё таки с моей стороны, потому что наврятле разработчики допустили ошибку и не пофиксили её через огромный промежуток времени с даты релеза движка.

Comment: на хостинге, кстате работает нормально, а на локалхосте ошибка

Answer (score 3):

Для тех, кто сталкивается еще с этой проблемой. В `phpmyadmin` делаю запрос:

```
set global sql_mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

или можно в коде сайта в `php` один раз запустить такой запрос.

делается 1 раз и мускул сервер запоминает.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблема решается так:

> sql-mode="" in my.ini file

перезапускаем MySQL

оказывается, по дефолту MySQL настроен по чётким стандартам SQL

> sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: я это уже писал

Comment: а где это файл находиться?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `a_test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `access` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

поля NOT NULL должны быть заполнены при INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема не с синтаксисом а с проектированием этой таблицы. Попробуйте для начала разрешить `NULL` в поле `description`:

```
ALTER TABLE `a_test` MODIFY COLUMN `description` TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
```

Но тогда на вашем `INSERT`-е будет выдаваться другая ошибка:

```
Field 'password' doesn't have a default value
```

Тогда можно исправить запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `a_test` SET `name` = 'Имя', `password` = '******'
```

И будет вам счастье :-)

P.S. Подумайте какие поля у вас обязательные и какие не обязательны, не обязательные поля можно сделать NULL-абельными. А обязательные для заполнения должны быть `NOT NULL` и не иметь `DEFAULT VALUE`.

Comment: он же в готовом движке юзает, там 100500 таблиц

Comment: Так дело не в движке а в таблице. Кто таблицу создает? Движок? Если да - то какой это движок если он знает что у него есть обязательные поля и не заполняет их? Хреновый движок.

Comment: пфф, но есть же готовый дамп от движка, какая разница, кто заливает его?

Comment: если залить движок на хостинг, то всё работает, даже тот пример, который привел тоже работает. Как такое возможно, если поля должны быть не пустыми?

Comment: я же говорю, дело не в дампе, а в настройке мускула

Comment: Тогда какая-то засада с MySQL-сервером, вот например bug-report на аналогичную тему: [MySQL bug#14306][1]

  [1]:http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14306

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто подключается через PDO можно использовать опцию, которая инициализирует нужный запрос при запуске - **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND** 
*(будет дейстовать для текущего соединения, не меняя настройки MySQL)*

Чтобы избежать 500 ошибку от MySQL из-за типов - например

> Field 'description' doesn't have a default value,  Incorrect integer
>   value: '' for column,  Field 'field' doesn't have a default value

(часто бывает, что локально работает, на сервере - нет) - ставим

```
SET sql_mode=""
```

Вот так для установления соединения без ошибок с типами:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";port=".DB_PORT;
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode=""'
];
try {   
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error! " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло добавление в docker-compose.yaml в секцию mysql:

```
mysql:
    container_name: #######
    platform: ######
    image: "######"
    command: mysqld --sql_mode=""
    networks:
       - ########
```